# PHP SOAP : How can I return objects from PHP using SOAP?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I need to send/return objects or array to/from PHP using SOAP. Any good links?

Answer (score 2):

I am using Zend_Soap_Server и Zend_Soap_Client. I send/receive array of difficult structure.

At first create class with structure you want to receive.

```
<?php

/**
 * Information about people
 */
class PeopleInformation
{
    /**
     * Name of ...
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * Age of
     * @var int
     */
    public $age;

    /**
     * Array of family
     *
     * @var FamilyInformation[]
     */
    public $family;
}

/**
 * Information about his family
 */
class FamilyInformation
{
    /**
     * Mother/sister/bro etc
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $relation;

    /**
     * Name
     * @var string
     */
    public $name;
}

?>
```

Then create service to receive this data:

```
<?php

/**
 * Service to receive SOAP data
 */
class SoapService
{
    /**
     *
     * @param PeopleInformation $data
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserData($data)
    {
        //here $data is object of PeopleInformation class


        return "OK";
    }
}
?>
```

Now create Zend_Soap_Server instance in controller by url http://ourhost/soap/:

```
<?php

//disable wsdl caching
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache', 0);

$wsdl = $_GET['wsdl'];

//this generate wsdl from our class SoapService
if (!is_null($wsdl))
{
    $autodiscover = new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover('Zend_Soap_Wsdl_Strategy_ArrayOfTypeSequence');
    $autodiscover->setClass('SoapService');
    $autodiscover->handle();
}
//handle all soap request
else
{
    $wsdlPath = 'http://ourhost/soap/?wsdl';

    $soap = new Zend_Soap_Server($wsdlPath, array(
        'cache_wsdl' => false
    ));
    $soap->registerFaultException('Zend_Soap_Server_Exception');
    $soap->setClass('SoapService');
    $soap->handle();
}

?>
```

And now you get wsdl (http://ourhost/soap/?wsdl) with you structure and handle request in *SoapService::getUserData*. Input parametr in this method is object of *PeopleInformation* class

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to create a class map and pass it to your soap client. Yes it is a pain. I usually just have a method that maps the Soap Object name to PHP objects (i.e. `Person => MY_Person`) and only code the ones I need to by hand (i.e `createdOn => DateTime`).

```
class MY_WSHelper
{  
  protected static $ws_map;  
  public static function make_map()
  {
    if( ! self::$ws_map)
    {
      self::$ws_map = array();
      //These will be mapped dynamically
      self::$ws_map['Person'] = NULL;
      self::$ws_map['Animal'] = NULL;
      //Hard-coded type map
      self::$ws_map['createdOn'] = DateTime;
      self::$ws_map['modifiedOn'] = DateTime;

      foreach(self::$ws_map as $soap_name => $php_name)
      {
        if($php_name === NULL)
        {
          //Map un-mapped SoapObjects to PHP classes
          self::$ws_map[$soap_name] = "MY_" . ucfirst($soap_name);
        }
      }
    }
    return self::$ws_map;
  }
}
```

Client:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://someurl.com/personservice?wsdl',
  array('classmap' => MY_WSHelper::make_map()));

$aperson = $client->getPerson(array('name' => 'Bob'));  
echo get_class($aperson); //MY_Person  
echo get_class($aperson->createdOn); //DateTime
```

http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

Answer (score 0):

Papa Google points me to this [Zend article](http://devzone.zend.com/article/689) with lots of good examples on both the client and server aspects of working with Soap (in particular PHP5's implementation of it).  Looks like a good starting point.

If you're somewhat like me, and cringe at the thought of writing up a WSDL by hand, I'd recommend using [WSHelper](http://www.jool.nl/new/1,webservice_helper.html), which uses PHP's reflection classes to dynamically generate a WSDL for you.  Definitely a time-saver

Answer (score 0):

I replay to share my (bad) experience.

I've created a webservice using PHP ZendFramework2 (ZF2).

The server reply objects and array of objects, and until it taken string as input it worked well. I was using the **ArrayOfTypeComplex** strategy.

```
$_strategy = new \Zend\Soap\Wsdl\ComplexTypeStrategy\ArrayOfTypeComplex();
```

When I try to use an array of string as input I felt in a dark and unhappy valley until I found Ramil's answer, so I change strategy and all work right!

```
$_strategy = new \Zend\Soap\Wsdl\ComplexTypeStrategy\ArrayOfTypeSequence();

if (isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
    $autodiscover = new \Zend\Soap\AutoDiscover($_strategy);
    $autodiscover->setBindingStyle(array('style' => 'document'));
    $autodiscover->setOperationBodyStyle(array('use' => 'literal'));
    $autodiscover->setClass('Tracker\Queue\Service')
        ->setUri($_serverUrl);
    echo $autodiscover->toXml();
}
```