# Passing user-defined types in PHP SOAP

Tags: php, soap, types

I'm having trouble understanding how to pass user-defined types in PHP SOAP calls. Could someone give me a hint (or a link to a manual) please?

Example:
In my WSDL file, I define the type:

```
<types>
<schema targetNamespace="http://example.com/CustData"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema">
  <element name="personalInformation">
    <complexType>
      <all>
        <element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <element name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
        <element name="lang" type="xsd:string"/>
      </all>
    </complexType>
  </element>
</schema>
```

I define the service response message like this:

```
<message name='getCustDataResponse'>
<part name='Result' type='xsd:personalInformation'/>
<part name='Result1' type='xsd:string'/>
</message>
```

The missing part is - how do I initialize the answer on the SOAP server side?

I tried writing:

```
$arrRes['Result']['name'] = 'xxx';
$arrRes['Result']['title'] = 'yyy';
$arrRes['Result']['lang'] = 'zzz';
$arrRes['Result']['hehehehe1'] = 'test1';
$arrRes['Result']['hehehehe2'] = 'test2';
$arrRes['Result']['hehehehe3'] = 'test3';
$arrRes['Result']['hehehehe4'] = 'test4';
$arrRes['Result1'] = 'result1';
$arrRes['blablabla'] = 'hahaha';
return $arrRes;
```

The client gets the response back and when I var_dump it, it shows the arrRes:

```
array(2) { ["Result"]=>  array(7) { ["name"]=>  string(3) "xxx" ["title"]=>  string(3) "yyy" ["lang"]=>  string(3) "zzz" ["hehehehe1"]=>  string(5) "test1" ["hehehehe2"]=>  string(5) "test2" ["hehehehe3"]=>  string(5) "test3" ["hehehehe4"]=>  string(5) "test4" } ["Result1"]=>  string(7) "result1" }
```

I expected to get an error because the array I initialized doesn't match the response message I have defined.

So I guess the type I have defined in the wsdl isn't used at all - so it must be an error either in the wsdl or in the client or server code.

Thanks in advance for your advice!!

Nikola

Comment: Nobody has a clue?

I've been searching the net quite a while now, and there's no precise instructions on complex types usage....

It seems that we can make a classmap when initializing the server, but I'm not quite sure how that works...

Any advice is welcome...

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done much with the server-side of SOAP on php, but [here is an example of how to use class mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006771/php-soap-how-can-i-return-objects-from-php-using-soap/3891690#3891690) with php's SoapClient. I am fairly certain that SoapServer works the exact same way. (You could probably even share the same class map between server/client).

So you would have a class like this:

```
class PersonalInformation
{
public $name;
public $title:
public $lang;
}
```

Then for your response:

```
function getCustData()
{
    $response = new PersonalInformation;
    $response->name = "Me";
    $response->title = "Hi World";
    $response->lang = "En-US";

    $arrResult = array();
    $arrResult['Result'] = $response;
    $arrResult['Result1'] = 'lol';
    return $arrResult
}
```

Then just use a class map like:

```
$server = new SoapServer('foo?wsdl', classmap=array('personalInformation' => 'PersonalInformation'));
//I'm not sure whether you have to use the classmap on BOTH server/client
$client = new SoapClient('foo?wsdl', classmap=array('personalInformation' => 'PersonalInformation'));
```

As far as the errors on non-conforming *response* data, I don't think php really does any validation on the reponse - only the request.