# PHP: How to do a SOAP request with complexTypes?

Tags: php, soap, complextype

I'm using Php default SoapClient for communication. I have to send data that looks something like this.

```
 <payloadPublication d2p1:type="GenericPublication" >
     ...
 </payloadPublication>
```

the only problem is how to add complexType "GenericPublication" in following code, everything else is working.

```
 $payloadPublication = array('payloadPublication'=> "subtags/data");
```

Comment: Can you update with more details on the data

Comment: One way is to directly use XML instead of making objects and that worked for me.  http://www.herongyang.com/WSDL/PHP-SOAP-SoapVar-Create-Encoded-Values.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the other answers but I solved my problem by sending XML directly and that worked for me.

$myxml = " all the xml that you want to send ***in the Soap request Body***";

$xmlvar = new SoapVar($myxml,XSD_ANYXML);

$params->xmlDocument = (object)$xmlvar;

$save_result = $client->yourFunctionName($xmlvar);

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here based on the example you provided (more info about the service would be helpful), but basically you would just do something like this:

```
class MYGenericPublication {
  public $subtags;
  public $name;
}

$new_pub = new MYGenericPublication;
$new_pub->subtags = array('tagA', 'tagB');
$new_pub->name = 'HiThere';

$client = new SoapClient('foo?wsdl', classmap=array('GenericPublication' => 'MYGenericPublication'));
$client->doSomethingWithPublication(array('payloadPublication' => $new_pub));

$my_pub = $client->findPublication(array('name' => 'HiThere'));
echo $my_pub->subtags[0]; // tagA
echo $my_pub->name; // HiThere
echo get_class($my_pub); // MYGenericPublication
```

See my answer here: [Passing user-defined types in PHP SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312022/passing-user-defined-types-in-php-soap/3988628#3988628) for more details

Comment: That wouldn't work when communicating with .NET based SOAP server.

Comment: Maybe I'm ignorant here. But why wouldn't it work with a .NET server?

Comment: I'm not sure maybe I'm ignorant here but I kept getting error "The specified type is abstract: name='Object'" where Object is  <payloadPublication d2p1:type="Object" >  I tried to send xml directly and that worked for me.